# Finding groups within time series in Postgre

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

I have a list of timestamps and i want to tag them as a group when they are close enough (less than 15 sec intervall). This is what I want to have eventually :

| time | group number |
| --- | --- |
| 18:01:00 | 1 |
| 18:01:06 | 1 |
| 18:10:00 | / |
| 18:20:30 | 2 |
| 18:20:40 | 2 |
| 18:20:50 | 2 |
| 18:25:02 | / |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` and date comparisons to determine where a group begins.  Then use a cumulative sum.  You actually only want to include rows that have multiple rows in the group, so this is a little tricker than the simple gaps-and-islands problem:

```
select t.*,
       (case when prev_time > time - interval '15 second' or
                  next_time < time + interval '15 second'
             then sum(case when prev_time > time - interval '15 sec' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by time)
        end) as group_number
  from (select t.*,
               lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time,
               lead(time) over (order by time) as next_time
        from t
       ) t
```